# WebStorm HTML formatting error - Expecting newline or semicolon

Tags: html, angular, formatting, webstorm

I am editing an HTML page in WebStorm. For some reason it's treating regular text like a JavaScript statement and throwing errors on code check 'Expecting newline or semicolon'. If the text is within an anchor tag it does not give an error.

Is this a bug? My JavaScript version is set to ES6.

HTML text showing an error:

[image]

WebStorm code check error:

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`

Comment: [Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections](https://imgur.com/a/c3y63)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`
2. Please remove 3rd rule from the bottom (the one that has "IDE" in Scope column)

You somehow (accidentally) created such wrong injection rule and now every `<li>` tag is treated as AngularJS hence the warnings.

Comment: That was it Thank you so much!